# How do I give permission for apache to retrieve imgs from directory?

Tags: html, linux, apache, permissions, fedora

I'm using fedora and I need to set up apache so that it can retrieve images from a directory. So far it can write to my image directory since sending the command ...

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/profile-pics'

restorecon -v '/var/www/profile-pics'

but when I try to access these files through the localhost/profile-pics/my_pic.jpg, the URL isn't being found. And as I said before, my PHP script is able to upload images from the user and write to this directory. I just don't understand why I can't retrieve the images and send them back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allow access using a  section in your httpd or vhost configuration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: I tried adding the directory via ..

#<Directory "/var/www/profile-pics/">
#    AllowOveride None
#    Options None
#    Require all granted
#</Directory>


It still says URL not found.

Comment: Take out all those #'s, it's the line comment indicator in Apache config files. Every line starting with # is a comment and is ignored by the parser.

Comment: I did, it still says URL not found when I type http://localhost/profile-pics/default.jpg. The pic exists and I can see it in the directory. No mispellings or anything. Also I restarted apache.